'main' already defined in xxx.obj
When I create two separate c++ programms (for instance, a.cpp and b.cpp) in Visual Studio and put them into one project, it will show  'main' already defined in a.obj  if I run b.cpp .
I've already known that I can solve this problem by openning a.cpp 's properties and clicking 'yes' on the " exlude from generation ". But it seems a little complicated if there are a lot of programms under one project and I want to run one of them, for then I'll have to repeat this procedure on each programm.
So I'm looking for other solutions that are more convenient ( such as "one click for all objects" or "set default values" , or simply change the basic structure of a c++ programm like not typing "int main()"?)

In Visual Studio, each project corresponds to one program (or a library). If you want to group multiple programs together, you should create a solution with multiple projects in it.

Thx. It turns out I've been using Visual Studio in a wrong way.  QAQ
